# General and geometric prescription of Picture-changing operator (PCO), Polchinski Vol.2, section 12.5

Tags: operators, string-theory, supersymmetry, s-matrix-theory, ghosts

In section 12.5, Polchinski tried to give a general description of PCO from a super-riemann surface view. He gave the generalized amplitude,

> *The measure on supermoduli space*
>
> The expression $(5.4.19)$ for the bosonic string S-matrix now generalizes in a natural way,$$S(1 ; \ldots ; n)=\sum_{\chi, \gamma} \frac{e^{-\lambda \chi}}{n_{R}} \int_{\chi, \gamma} d^{n_{\mathrm{e}}} t d^{n_{\mathrm{o}}} v\left\langle\prod_{j=1}^{n_{\mathrm{e}}} B_{j} \prod_{a=1}^{n_{\mathrm{o}}} \delta\left(B_{a}\right) \prod_{i=1}^{n} \hat{\mathscr{V}}_{i}\right\rangle\tag{12.4.24}$$The sum is over topologies $ \chi $ and spin structures $ \gamma . $ The integral runs over the corresponding supermoduli space. There are $ n_{\mathrm{e}} $ even moduli, $ n_{\mathrm{o}} $ odd moduli, and $ n $ external strings. The quantity $ B_{j} $ in the ghost insertions is$$B_{j}=\sum_{(m n)} \int_{C_{m n}} \frac{d z_{m} d \theta_{m}}{2 \pi i} B\left(z_{m}, \theta_{m}\right)\left[\frac{\partial z_{m}}{\partial t_{j}}-\frac{\partial \theta_{m}}{\partial t_{j}} \theta_{m}\right]_{z_{n}, \theta_{n}}\tag{12.4.25}$$plus a right-moving piece of the same form; $ B_{a} $ is given by an identical expression with $ v_{a} $ replacing $ t_{j} $. The sum again runs over all pairs of

Then he turned to a simple model with just considering two patches and only one odd modulus.

> It is interesting to work out the form of the amplitude more explicitly for a special choice of patches and transition functions. Namely, let patch 1 be contained entirely within patch 2, so that the overlap is an annulus. Let the 1-2 transition functions depend only on a single odd modulus $ v $, as follows:$$f_{12}\left(z_{2}\right)=z_{2}, \quad g_{12}\left(z_{2}\right)=v \alpha\left(z_{2}\right)\tag{12.5.27}$$for some holomorphic function $ \alpha(z) $. The ghost factor $ (12.5 .25) $ is proportional to$$B[\alpha]=\oint \frac{d z_{1}}{2 \pi i} \alpha\left(z_{1}\right) \beta\left(z_{1}, \theta\right)\tag{12.5.28}$$Similarly the path integral depends on $ v $ only through the insertion$$v T[\alpha]\tag{12.5.29}$$where $ \beta $ is replaced by $ T_{F} $. We can then perform the integration over $ v $, so that the net effect of the supermodulus is the insertion in the path integral of$$T[\alpha] \delta(B[\alpha])=Q_{\mathrm{B}} \cdot \theta(B[\alpha])\tag{12.5.30}$$

I understand most of the section, but $(12.5.29)$ and $(12.5.30)$.

It seems $(12.5.29)$ should be from $\delta_{BRST}S(1,2,...,n)$, not from the amplitude $S(1,2,...,n)$, since $\delta_{B}(b,\partial_k g)=(T,\partial_k g)$.

I can guess for $(12.5.30)$ but an exact and explicit calculation is preferred.